# How do I add multiple classes/IDs to this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, if I want to add more than one class or ID, how would I go about doing that?

```
$("#main-content").customScrollbar();
```

So, let's say I want `customScrollbar();` to be applied to both `#main-content` and `.song-list`. Can I separate them with commas?

Comment: *"Can I separate them with commas?"* Yes, you can.

Comment: Yes, you can pass multiple selectors to jquery... Did you try, or read the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

use `,`

```
$("#main-content,.song-list").customScrollbar();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/